# Firefox: how to autocomplete password but not username

Tags: firefox, passwords, autocomplete, username

I'm a part of a team testing a web application that needs to log into hundreds of test accounts every day. The password is always the same, but the usernames constantly change. I can save the password without an accompanying username, but then it won't autocomplete when I next visit the site.

I am hoping to get Firefox to autocomplete the password field but not the username field. To make things more difficult, we're unable to use any third party addons or software because of legal restrictions. We're also unable to modify the login page on the server's side.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: you could use greasemonkey to auto fill in but that might class as third party...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK the most simple solution is to use Javascript to create a **bookmarklet**.

Here's an example of *autocomplete bookmarklet* which can be adapted to your needs by a good programer in Javascript:

[Form auto-fill bookmarklet](http://www.phpied.com/form-auto-fill-bookmarklet/)

Comment: Good idea. Do you know if it's possible to have both the URL and the bookmarklet saved together so pressing the bookmark takes you to the login page AND fills it out? My goal is to have the password passively filled out so that people don't have to change their usual habits.

Answer (score 2):

[Saved Password Editor](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/saved-password-editor/) does this (and I assume it is not classed as a third party add-on ).

I tested this and it works on Amazon.

If it doesn't allow you to save without a username, then enter the username, save it, and then edit it and remove the user name)

Comment: Unfortunately that addon does count as third party software so the team can't use it. If I can find a way to modify the password on just one computer I could probably then share it via firefox's password sync tool.